# How to describe a polynomial relation on $\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^k V)$, and if the Zariski topology is canonical

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, definition, intuition

I am working with the space $\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^k V)$, where $V$ is some $n$ dimensional vector space over some field K. In here I want to define a variety, ie a solution to a set of polynomials. But I run into the problem that I am actually not sure how the correspondence between the variable in my polynomials (the algebra side) and my projective space (the geometry) is made. This is how I see things now:

When given a vector space $V$ over a field $K$, we choice a basis $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$. This gives us a set of maps 
$$x_i:V\to K: \sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i\mapsto a_i$$
Now one can associate to a polynomial $p\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ a map $\tilde{p}:V\to K$ by setting
$$\tilde{p}(v)=\sum_{I}c_ix_{I_1}(v)\cdots x_{I_n}(v)$$
For a projectivized space one now restricts as usual to homogeneous polynomials and then one can talk about their zero's.

And hence the correspondence between our geometry and algebra ultimately depends on a choice of basis for our space. But this raises two questions:

1. Is the zariski topology, which is defined in terms of solutions to systems of polynomials, canonical? i.e. do we get the same topology if we would have chosen a different basis and expressed our polynomials w.r.t. the coordinates induced by this basis.
2. Is there any way of describing a polynomial in a coordinate independent way? So if I have an object sitting in $\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^k V)$ (of course I'm talking about the Plucker embedding of the Grassmannian), can I describe this object as a variety without choosing coordinates on $\bigwedge^k V$?

The answer to my first question is clearly 'yes, the zariski topology is canonical, since the transition from one set of coordinates to another is given by polynomial equations'. I would still like someone's input on this question though, since I've never seen it discussed anywhere; no one ever shows this or talks about this, which makes me doubt that this is a question that makes sense.

The answer to my second question I think is 'no, there is no way to do this without choosing coordinates', but again I would like someone's input on this to maybe get some more insight.

Comment: 1. Yes. You don't need to pick a basis of anything to talk about the Zariski topology. 2. Polynomials on a vector space $V$ are elements of the symmetric algebra $\text{Sym}(V^{\ast})$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for pointing me to the symmetric algebra, I'd never heard of it, but from what I read on wikipedia, it seems to solve exactly this problem.  As for (1), do you agree that technically when the Zariski topology is introduced, one should check independence of the choice of coordinates, even if it might be obvious?

Comment: No. You don't need to pick coordinates to talk about the Zariski topology in the first place.

Comment: A polynomial on $V$ is an element $f \in \text{Sym}(V^{\ast})$. This definition allows you to give a coordinate-independent description of the evaluation $f(v)$ of a polynomial at a point $v \in V$ (exercise), and from there you can define the zero set of $f$.